# Making a proxy from the Nextjs api does not work with next-http-proxy-middleware

Tags: reactjs, proxy, next.js, http-proxy-middleware

I'm trying to make a proxy out of the nextjs api, but it seems like it doesn't work.

My pages/api/index.js looks like this:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import httpProxyMiddleware from 'next-http-proxy-middleware';

const API_SERVICE_URL = "https://api.company.io/";

export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  console.log('api', req, res)
  return httpProxyMiddleware(req, res, {
    target: API_SERVICE_URL
  })
}
```

I've the feeling it doesn't reach this, because the log never shows. So, I've moved it to `pages/api/[...all]` but this doesn't change anything. Anyone know how to use the Nextjs api to make a proxy?

Comment: The code seems fine. How are you trying to reach the API route, and where are you looking for the `console.log`?

Comment: @juliomalves the problem was in the file name

Answer (score 3):

For reference purposes I will answer the question myself

I changed the file name from `index.js` to `[...all]` this way the middleware responds to all api calls instead of just https://localhost:8000/api